# Treeview duplicates the value in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

[image: screenshot]

When I click the refresh button it queries the data from SQL database, but in the list box it duplicate the values

```
def show():

    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="1986@", database="ecogreen")
    mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT id,Firstname,Lastname,Mobile,Location FROM customers1")
     records = mycursor.fetchall()

    for i, (id, Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, Location) in enumerate(records, start=2):
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=(id, Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, Location))
        mysqldb.close()
```

I tried to include the clear and delete function, but it is not working, can some one please help me

Warm Regards
Janarthanan

Comment: You need to clear `listBox` before populating data from database.

Comment: _"I tried to include the clear and delete function, but it is not working, "_ - you need to show what you tried, and why you think it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear `listBox` before populating data from database:

```py
def show():
    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="1986@", database="ecogreen")
    mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT id,Firstname,Lastname,Mobile,Location FROM customers1")
    records = mycursor.fetchall()
    mysqldb.close()

    # clear table
    listBox.delete(*listBox.get_children())
    # populate table
    for i, (id, Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, Location) in enumerate(records, start=2):
        listBox.insert("", "end", values=(id, Firstname, Lastname, Mobile, Location))
```

Comment: `listBox.delete(0, "end")` is a little simpler.

Comment: @BryanOakley `listBox` is an instance of `Treeview` but not a `Listbox` based on the image and the code.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. _sigh_ I really should stay off of StackOverflow when I'm tired. Apologies!

Comment: It should be id_entry.delete(0, "end"), firstname_entry.delete(0, "end"), etc